What is quicker - restore with replace or deleting DB and then making restore - for DB with simple recovery mode?
What is quicker - restore with replace or deleting DB and then making restore (for DB with simple recovery model (log file = 0) and size of data file of 2Tb)?

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please provide your RDBMS and version in the tags and/or the text of your question. I'm guessing SQL Server, but can't be sure. The more and more detailed information that you provide, the more likely it is that you'll receive a good answer - HTH!

Restore with replace is quicker, you are saving time for zero initialization at least of your log file, and in case of absence of Database instant file initialization
your drop + restore will cause zero initialization of 2Gb of datafile
